# python csv convert to nest dictionary

Tags: python, csv

my csv file is below

```
Uid,locate,category,act

Anna,NY,house,dance
Anna,LA,house,sing
Anna,CH,house,ride
John,NY,house,dance
John,LA,home,sing
John,CH,home,ride
```

and i want to create dictionary just like

```
{'Uid': 'Anna', 'infos':[{'locate': 'NY', 'category': 'house', 'act': 'dance'},
                        {'locate': 'LA', 'category': 'house', 'act': 'sing'},
                        {'locate': 'CH', 'category': 'house', 'act': 'ride'}]
},
{'Uid': 'John', 'infos':[{'locate': 'NY', 'category': 'house', 'act': 'dance'},
                        {'locate': 'LA', 'category': 'home', 'act': 'sing'},
                        {'locate': 'CH', 'category': 'home', 'act': 'ride'}]
},
```

my code is below:

```
result = {}
with open('test.csv') as fp:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fp)
    for row in reader:
        result['test_uid'] = row['Uid']
        result["test_locate"] = row['locate']
        result["test_category"] = row['category']
        result["test_act"] = row['act']
print(result)
```

how to append the infos datas to the same person?

how to fix my code that can print the result I want??

Need someone help please.

Comment: what is your output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your output looks like a list, but you need a dictionary. Try this:

```
result = {}
with open('test.csv') as fp:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fp)
    for row in reader:
        uid = row['Uid']
        del row['Uid']
        if uid in result:
            result[uid]['infos'].append(row)
        else:
            result[uid] = {'infos': [row]}

print(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
payload = {}
# first let create a dict with uid as a key and a list of infos as a value.
with open('test.csv') as fp:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fp)
    for row in reader:
        data = {"locate": row['locate'], 'category': row['category'],
                          'act': row['act']}
        if row['Uid'] in payload.keys():
            payload[row['Uid']].append(data)
        else:
            payload[row['Uid']] = [data]

# reconstruct the payload to be list of dicts in the structure you want 
result = list(map(lambda uid, infos: {'Uid':uid, 'infos':infos}, payload.items()))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would change the resulting datastructure a bit so it becomes easier to handle:

```
result = {}
with open('test.csv') as fp:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fp)
    for row in reader:
        if row['Uid'] not in result:
            result[row['Uid']] = [{
                'test_locate': row['locate'],
                'test_category': row['category'],
                'test_act': row['act']}]
        else:
            result[row['Uid']].append({
                'test_locate': row['locate'],
                'test_category': row['category'],
                'test_act': row['act']})
print(result)
```

Comment: WOW!  This datastructure is more simple than I want , thank your for your idea !!!

Answer (score 0):

The result you are showing is actually a list of dictionaries. If that is what you want, then:

```
result = []
with open('test.csv') as fp:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fp)
    infos = []
    last_uid = None
    for row in reader:
        uid = row['Uid']
        if uid != last_uid:
            if last_uid is not None:
                result.append({'Uid': last_uid, 'infos': infos})
                last_uid = uid
                infos = []
            last_uid = uid
        infos.append({'locate': row['locate'], 'category': row['category'], 'act': row['act']})
    if last_uid is not None:
        result.append({'Uid': last_uid, 'infos': infos})
```